# How to add an "entry point arrow" to a tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

In Xcode 6.2 beta, I am able to make some view controllers such as "View Controller" or "Navigation view controller" the entry point of my interface by dragging and dropping the "entry point arrow" on it, it gives me something like this :
[image]
But when I want to drag this arrow on a tab bar controller, it does not work, so is that a bug or should I do it in another way ?

Comment: @AshishKakkad What view controller ? I have only my Tab bar controller.

Comment: Delete the tab bar controller, add a normal view controller and then embed it in a tab bar controller

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh, OK thank you ! Hope Apple will make it easier in the future.

Answer (score 156):

Try with following steps.

1) Open `StoryBoard`.

2) select `TabbarController`which you want to set as `RootViewController`.

3) Open `Properties`.

4) select `InitialView Controller` Option.

For help you can see following `image`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work anymore with the newest version of Xcode (Xcode 6.2 I think, it was still possible in Xcode 6.1 if I remember...)

Comment: Make sure that you select the View Controller boarder (the white part), not the middle part of the view controller, because that's something else. See this image.  http://i.imgur.com/3tD99Dy.png

Answer (score 20):

its a litile bit confusing over versions on xCode, I'm using version 8.3.2 and it has the follwing

select navigation controller

[image: select navigation controller]

check the is initial view controller checkbox

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zADY.png)[[image: select is initial view controller]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zADY.png)

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. The Answer above solved it using Xcode 6.4. So I think this is the right answer. But as I can´t comment to provide this alternative, I write a new answer

It is also possible to:

1. open the `StoryBoard` per `Open as` `Source Code`
2. In the XML `<document>` tag you can add the `initialViewController="viewVontrollerID"` tag
3. replace the `"viewVontrollerID"` with the id of the ViewController, that the application should start with. (keep the "")

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the "initial view controller" checkbox at first.  Then I realized that this is because I was in the "Table View" not the "Table View Controller."  When I clicked into the "Table View Controller" that checkbox appeared.

*Xcode View*
[image]