# ViewController is loading always the same link

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview, swift4

I am new to swift and ios.The View Controller launch always the same link and do do not show the grid menu with buttons that is in second scene.What i am doing wrong here?
I have in main.storyboard three scene.

In the first scene is navigation.The second scene is a grid menu with    buttons that depending on the button click will open a link in webview located in the 3rd scene.The third scene includes a view that should open a specific link depending on the click button in step 2

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView :  WKWebView!
    var webi:String =  "https://www.google.al"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("‼️OMG:viewDidLoad", webi)
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: webi)!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))

        let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))
        toolbarItems = [refresh]
        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
    }

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    @IBAction func Menu1(_ sender: Any) {
        print("‼️OMG:viewDidLoad with menu1")
        webi =  "https://www.menu1.com"

    }

    @IBAction func Menu2(_ sender: Any) {
        print("‼️OMG:viewDidLoad with menu1")
        webi =  "https://www.menu2.com"
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        title = webView.title
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Be aware that `viewDidLoad` is called only **once**.

Comment: Please can you help me.I am new to ios.I want to build a grid of button that every button open different link.The problem that i have it open directly the webview with google link and does not show the grid menu.I have stucked here.

Comment: Put the two lines to load the web data into a method and call the method in `viewDidLoad` and in the two `IBAction`s

Comment: Except the `viewDidLoad` call at once part try making your url request with `reloadIgnoringCacheData` to avoid caching for same request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you change the urlStr `webi` without reloading the `webview` again

```
func refresh() { 
  let url = URL(string: webi)!
  webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
@IBAction func Menu1(_ sender: Any) {
    print("‼️OMG:viewDidLoad with menu1")
    webi =  "https://www.menu1.com"
    self.refresh()
}

@IBAction func menu2(_ sender: Any) {
    print("‼️OMG:viewDidLoad with menu1") // other link
    webi =  "https://www.menu1.com"
    self.refresh()
}
```

///

> Navigation->buttons Menu VC -> webViewVC

while your are in buttons menu

```
 let vc = ViewController()
 vc.webi = "" // set link according to the clicked button
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,animated:true)
```

Look to this [Demo](https://github.com/ShKhan9/webViewDemo)

Comment: During the app launching it shows not the grid menu but it open direct the webview?What i need is after launching the app will need to show the grid menu with buttons and on button clickt it must open a link in webview.

Comment: by scene do you mean a vc ? also do you make  the storyboard entry point or the arrow that appear middle left  to the navigation ?

Comment: you must create a vc for the buttons menu , don't implement it inside the webviewVC

Comment: select the navigation in storyboard then do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683590/how-to-add-an-entry-point-arrow-to-a-tab-bar-controller

Comment: I have main.Stroryboard and inside it i have 3 Scene ( VC )  1 Webview 2 grid menu and 3 navigation

Comment: I will try and let you know it tomorrow.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should  it be this let vc = // instantiate webviewVc from stroybaord .. inside a button function and second question is : let vc = what i need here to write? Thanks

Comment: yes but it inside the every menu button action , second since your vc is nearly created programmatically you can use what in edit

Comment: I have upload some picture to show you that the main menu is not showing.It open very fast the webview.What i am missing here?Thanks.

Comment: All the code is in ViewController.swift file.And the main.Storyboad has 3 Scene inside it.

Comment: I have uploaded some new Pic @Sh_Khan

Comment: @Didi why you re-assign the same google link inside the button action ????\

Comment: Sh_Khan the problem is that the main menu is not opening or is opened very fast. What you have said is true i must change it later.My problem is that  wenn the app is launching it open direct the webview..It must open the meun and if i click one button than it must open the specific link according the button.

Comment: Do you understand my question.The user after the app is launching should see grid menu than if the person click the button it will open a website in the webview.

Comment: you put both in the same vc , please create a separate class for the grids

Comment: @Didi see the attached demo

Comment: I got this error2019-01-17 12:59:49.635074+0000 IOS-Swift-WebView[27811:329091] -[IOS_Swift_WebView.ViewControllerMenu Menu1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fccc3503b60
2019-01-17 12:59:49.643699+0000 IOS-Swift-WebView[27811:329091] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[IOS_Swift_WebView.ViewControllerMenu Menu1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fccc3503b60'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5af1bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331

Comment: it appears that you removed the action method for that button , please follow the demo exactly

Comment: Thank you it works.Please can you tell me how to send some special string with http webview to the webserver. Becuase i want to catch this string in the http server.I have done this thing with android but here i do not know it.webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("didi");